# Is Xcode 6.1.1 ISO standard for C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, iso

Is Xcode 6.1.1 ISO standard C++ compliant? If not, how can I set it to require ISO standard C++? I have to submit my C++ project as ISO standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode uses `clang` by default and [clang definitely supports ISO C++](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html), you just have to use the right flags.

If you go to your projects *Build Settings*, you can configure the standard you want to use under *Language - C++*, for example C++11 or GNU C++11(*which would include non-standard extensions*). So you would want C++11, C++14 etc...

Then you want to enable pedantic warnings under *Warning Policies* which will generate a warning for any non-standard construct you are using.

The equivalent command line flags let's say for C++11 would be:

```
-std=c++11 -pedantic
```